# deals with hidden folder

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We are a little company in france, and we have developed a add-in for outlook, that used the WS exchange and VSTO. We need to develope this plugins for office 365
How can we deals with hidden folder inside a outlook mailbox ?
With WS Exchange we can hide a folder in the directory of an outlook account. We can send an SingleValueExtendedProperties (0x104f : true) to make that. 
Whit the office 365 we can send this same SingleValueExtendedProperties the folder is correctly hide, but after that we can't list them, we can't move them, we can't delete them... a ghost, but when we cant to create a folder whit the same name, we get an error that indicate a folder already exists...

Folder list
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders

create folder

```
POST 
https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/MailFolders/{folder_id}/childfolders
{
    "DisplayName": "Business"
}
```

Update folder : rename + hide -> 404 but no floder after that

```
PATCH https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/MailFolders/AAMkAGNlZmM5OTBlLTMwZTgtNGQzZS1iM2IzLTRjNWNkZDNlMTU4NAAuAAAAAADp0G8t0SUuQJyWc5hKYYdzAQA76fHUOjd6RImcXSS_fEDDAAAAADIrAAA=
{
    "DisplayName": "test",
    "SingleValueExtendedProperties":[
        {
        "PropertyId":"Boolean 0x10f4",
        "Value": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

after this rest call, folder is hidden and unusable...

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is obvious. It won't allow to create new folder with the same name as it is just hiding the folder not removing permanently.

For Office 365 I would rather recommend you to use Outlook Web Add in template and for code Microsoft graph as It is providing all office 365 products api at single place. Then after you won't need to use VSTO Addin. single development will work for both Outlook client application and Outlook online.

screenshot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/images/uiless-command-shape.png

ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/

Answer (score 0):

Yes we adapt the addins to office 365 with graph api. But this for me is a bug in graph api. We can hide a folder and after all command sent an 404 error, folder not found.

If we have hide a folder, the rest api whould offer the possibility to move, edit, unhide, delete, list this item. In my case with a 365 office cloud instance, i can't made anything whit this folder, the administration panel of my company can't display folders of an user account, the user account administration panel can't edit the folder list. How can i manage this "ghost" folder.